# Compile CLASSPATH in a Windows batchfile

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, classpath

On a Unix systems it's very easy to compile the CLASSPATH by using find:

```
LIBDIR=`find lib/ -name \*.jar`
for DIR in $LIBDIR:
do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$DIR"
done

java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.example.MyClass
```

What would be the aquivalent in a Windows batchfile?

Comment: Why not use a build tool such as ant or maven? They can compile classpath entries in a platform independent manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same can be achieved from Windows XP on with:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R .\lib %%G IN (*.jar) DO set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%G

java -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.example.MyClass
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows XP, unless you've run cmd /v first

Comment: Indeed it does if you set the ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION variable as described above (I forgot to add it initially, hence the edit) - just tested it seconds ago.

Comment: Bare in mind that if your classpath is long, then you can end up with an "input line too long" error message on Windows.... Maybe a way for Micro$oft to force people to actually point-and-click a runnable jar rather than the (apparently) evil pro-linux command line way of doing things :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is to use delayed environment variable expansion. You can do that by running

```
cmd /v
```

Then you can run:

```
set var=.
FOR /r %%d IN (*.jar) DO SET var=!var!;%%d
set CLASSPATH=%var%
```